# Compare string to integer in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, int

beginner student here.
I'm trying to make a game where the user is asked a riddle.
the correct answer is the current time written like this: hh:mm

The program works fine until the user inputs to many different wrong guesses (like random letters).
After that it gives error even if the answer is right.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    //check
    bool ok=false; //true when guess==real time
    int tent=0; //tryes
    //guesses
    char tempo[5]; //input string from user
    char ora[2];   //houres
    char min[2];   //mins
    //get time
    time_t my_time;
    struct tm * timeinfo; 
    time (&my_time);
    timeinfo = localtime (&my_time);
    //random
    srand(time(NULL));

    //guessing game, user shound input a string that conains current time to win:   hh:mm
    printf("In principio era uno, e il nulla.\n\n");
    printf("Poi l'uomo lo duplico', e tra essi traccio' la via...\n");
    printf("Lo fece ancora... e gli sembro' perfetto.\n");
    printf("Ma non era abbastanza... ");
    printf("Cosi' si spinse piu' in profondita', e sbirciando poco oltre trovo'...  ");

    do{
        //get guessed time (could also get words and non relevant numbers, if input is not hh:mm (current hour:current mins) user gets error)
        scanf("%s",&tempo);
        fflush(stdin);
        //split array tempo into ora and min to separate h from mins
        ora[0]=tempo[0];
        ora[1]=tempo[1];
        min[0]=tempo[3];
        min[1]=tempo[4];
        //cast guess form string to int
        int oraint=atoi(ora); //creat integer hour from string
        int minint=atoi(min); //integer mins

        //check guess == real time
        if(oraint==timeinfo->tm_hour && minint==timeinfo->tm_min){
            //win
            printf("\nCOMPLIMENTI! Hai trovato la risposta!\n");
            printf("\n\nEcco le tue prossime istruzioni!\n\n");
            printf("TURFeE1UQXdNREF3TVRFd01EQXdNVEF4TVRFd01ERXhNREV4TVRBd01URXdNVEV4TURFeE1UQXhNVEF4TVRFeE1ERXhNVEF3TVRBd01URXdNREV3TURBd01URXhNREV3TURBeE1EQXdNREF3TVRBd01ERXhNREF4TVRBeE1URXhNREV4TVRBeE1ERXdNVEV4TURBeE1EQXhNVEV3TVRBd01ERXhNREV3TURBd01UQXdNREV3TURBeE1UQXhNREF4TURFeE1ERXhNREV3TVRFd01ERXdNVEF4TVRBeE1URXdNREV4TVRBd01URXdNVEV3TVRBd01UQXhNVEF4TVRFeE1ERXhNREV4TVRBPQ==\n\n");
            printf("Che c'e'? devo anche dirti come decifrarle?\n");
            printf("...e va bene...ti do un'indizio\n");
            printf("Ricorda che, a volte, un colpo non basta.");
            ok=true;
        } else {
            tent++;
            int val=rand()%6; //random error pharases
            switch(val){
                case 0:
                    printf("Non ci siamo...\n\n");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("Pare di no...\n\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("Riprova.\n\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf("Pensaci meglio...\n\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf("Nah, prova ancora.\n\n");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printf("Ti ho mai detto quante risposte hai gia' provato?\n");
                    printf("Beh... sono ben ");
                    printf("%d\n\n",tent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }while(ok=true);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm experimenting with thing I didn't study, so please forgive stupid errors or bad code.. Thanks in advance

Comment: `while(ok=true);` is sure to be wrong.

Comment: Please ___properly___ indent your code. Machine (Compiler) can read and compile anything, but for humans, it needs to make a little _sense_ while reading a block of text as _code_. When asking question, there was a big orange __How to Format__ box to the right of the text area. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a __[?]__ button giving formatting help. And a preview area  showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Try `while(ok==true);` (note the `==` operator)

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy: why not `while(ok!=true);`?

Comment: In particular, `fflush(stdin)` is not guaranteed to have any effect whatever.  If you want to clear pending input then read and discard it.

Comment: Corrected array sizes and while argument, now the program works 100% of the times.
I know, really stupid errors.. 
Also sorry for bad indentation.. I'll keep it in mind for next time.
Thank you all for your help and quick responses!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: learn to use your debugger. Dont ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Some problems here:

```
scanf("%s",&tempo); 
fflush(stdin);
//split array tempo into ora and min to separate h from mins
ora[0]=tempo[0];
ora[1]=tempo[1];
min[0]=tempo[3];
min[1]=tempo[4];
//cast guess form string to int
int oraint=atoi(ora); //creat integer hour from string
int minint=atoi(min); //integer mins
```

Going line by line:

```
scanf("%s",&tempo);
```

Do not use the `&` operator when passing an array expression like `tempo` to `scanf` - array expressions are automatically converted to pointer expressions under most circumstances.  That line should simply be

```
scanf("%s", tempo);
```

Secondly, `tempo` isn't large enough to store the *string* "hh:mm" - remember that a string always has a terminating 0.  You need to allocate an array that's at least 1 element larger than the longest string you intend to store in it, so `tempo` should be declared as `char[6]`.

Third,

```
fflush(stdin);
```

is not defined in general; "flushing" an input stream simply doesn't make much sense.  It's true that Microsoft defined it to clear out the input stream in their particular implementations, but in general the line is nonsensical.  Don't expect it to work anywhere outside of a MSVC implementation.

Next,

```
ora[0]=tempo[0];
ora[1]=tempo[1];
min[0]=tempo[3];
min[1]=tempo[4];
```

Like `tempo`, `ora` and `min` are not *strings* - you haven't set aside any space for a string terminator.  `atoi` will not convert them properly.

You'll have to declare both `ora` and `min` as `char[3]`, and make sure that `ora[2]` and `min[2]` are set to 0:

```
ora[0] = tempo[0];
ora[1] = tempo[1];
ora[2] = 0;
min[0] = tempo[3];
min[1] = tempo[4];
min[2] = 0;
```

Of course, you can avoid *all* of this by using the following:

```
int ora;
int min;

if ( scanf( "%d:%d", &ora, &min ) == 2 )
{
  // read ora and min properly
} 
else
{
  // bad input or error
}
```

Finally,

```
while(ok=true);
```

needs to be either

```
while ( ok == true ); // == for comparison, = for assignment
```

or

```
while ( ok ); // my personal preference
```

`ok=true` *assigns* the value `true` to `ok` - to perform a comparison, use `ok == true`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help and time, as I said I nearly just started learning C, so your, and all of the comments, are really precious!